# AngularJS, min/max datetime input on mobile

Tags: angularjs, datetime, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile-friendly website with AngularJS and JQM. I have datetime field inputs like this one

```
<input type="datetime" max="2013-10-11T00:00:00Z"></input>
```

On mobile this looks like (for iOS)

[image]

The question: How to limit minimum and maximum datetime input on mobile? 
For instance, if 11 Oct. 2013 (from the image) is our max date the user should not swipe to 11th. Is this possible or I should choose some 3rd party datetime picker, if so - suggest one regarding the technologies I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min and max attributes for this or indeed look for a 3rd party solution. Just search for AngularJS date picker and several ones will pop up. The bootstrap one is quite nice.

Eg.

> min="1990-12-31T23:59:60Z"

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html)

Comment: Html5 min/max don't work on the picker I showed on the picture - the default one for iOS safari.

Comment: it was not clear to me that you added the min/max attributes since your example code lacks those.